# send 2d array integer data from c++ to qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Ive been searching whole day, but this questions bothers me so much.

Im creating a game (similar to "Lines") and im attempting to save the grid state (0 - if clear, > 0 - if stored some ball). I have a slot in my class:

```
int Game::getGridMap() {
    return gameGridArray[9][9];
}
```

and then:

```
onPressed: {
                buttonStart.color = "#222333"

                handleGame.initGame();
                var aRect = handleGame.getGridMap();
            }
```

but it returns "undefined" or smth like that.

what am i doing wrong? is that a better way to store these data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution!

First, i created:

```
QList<int> getGridMap();
```

and then created a list from a 2 dimentional array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            oChildList.append(gameGridArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

This values can be easely passed to QML. and then just turned it again in qml:

```
var aRect = create2DArray(9);
var aString = handleGame.getGridMap();

aRect = listToArray(aString);

function listToArray(arr) {
    var arr2d = new create2DArray(9);

    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            arr2d[i][j] = arr[i*9+j];
        }
    }

    return arr2d;
}

function create2DArray(rows) {
  var arr = [];

  for (var i=0;i<rows;i++) {
     arr[i] = [];
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: how are you passing handleGame.getGridMap() to QML? How does QML know what that function is?

Answer (score -1):

You need to put "Q_INVOCABLE" before definition of getGridMap() in Game class header file.

For example,

Q_INVOCABLE int getGridMap();

Comment: its already a slot, so its can be called from qml, but when my C++ funtion returns an array, when called from qml returns just 0.